# How to hide data of a specific cell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Datagridview

```
1    Drink1    Beef1
2    Drink2    Beef2
3    Drink3    Beef3
```

But now I want to hide only "Drink3" and the rest stay the same.

I'm only aware of how to hide/remove rows and columns but not sure if it's possible for an individual cell. If it is, what should I apply here? I'm thinking of an datagridview Event but just can't find what it is.

The result should look like this.

```
1    Drink1    Beef1
2    Drink2    Beef2
3              Beef3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the cell's style in the backend code, you can change the cell's String value to `""`.

Comment: Can't use CSS in windows forms

Answer (score 0):

If you want just don't show the value, you can clear it. You now `Cell` is read-only and you can change the `Visible` directly.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[Your Row].Cells[Your Col].Value = null;
```

If you need cell data you can achieve it from the `Data Table`.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the value - but you'll be deleting it from linked data source as well.

---

Other way to do it would be to set that cell's:

- `cell.CellStyle.ForeColor = cell.CellStyle.BackColor`
- `cell.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor = cell.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor`

Thus making data invisible.

But in this case user can still copy and paste the value, so you'd have to disable copying values from this `DataGridView` as whole or intercept copy event and if user is copying from "forbidden" cell, just cancel the event.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work on Visual Studio 2022 because CellStyle property doesn't exist !

Answer (score 0):

While you might hide the result as sugested, such as amending your forecolor and back color, I would not recommend it. In some cases (highlited content for instance) it **may become visible**.

If you don't need to work with the content after you load it into the `DataGridView`, you can erase the content directly in your data query (SQL, LINQ) or in `DataTable`.

If you have to work with the content at runtime after you load the `DataGridView`, than clone source `DataTable`, hide the content and present that new one. One can figure out more ways to apply this principle.

C#

```
DataTable dt;
dt = ds.table(0);

for (var ir = 0; ir <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; ir++)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.Rows(ir);   
    if (CStr(dr("MyColumn")) = "Drink3")
    {
        dr("MyColumn") = " ";
    }
}
this.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

VB:

```
Dim dt As DataTable
dt = ds.table(0)

For ir = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.Rows(ir)
    If CStr(dr("MyColumn")) = "Drink3" Then
        dr("MyColumn") = " "
    End If
Next
Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio 2022, I use following solution

```
cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White
cell.Style.BackColor = Color.White
```

Solution of `Kacper Turowski` doesn't work because

1. `CellStyle` property doesn't exist !
2. Initializing `ForeColor` from `BackColor` doesn't work when `BackColor` has not be changed !

My code (for example) is following

```
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
Dim sPreviousNoCompte As String = ""

Do While dr.Read()
    grid.Rows.Add()

    With grid.Rows(iRow)
        .Cells(0).Value = dr.Item("no_compte")
        .Cells(1).Value = dr.Item("validated")
        .Cells(2).Value = dr.Item("nom")

        If .Cells(0).Value = sPreviousNoCompte Then
            .Cells(0).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
            .Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.White
        End If
        iRow += 1
        sPreviousNoCompte = .Cells(0).Value
    End With
Loop
```